# I am getting null pointer exception while implementing setOnClickListener in a fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-fragments, android-developer-api

While implementing setOnClickListener inside a fragment and after running the app my app is crashing and logical attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference...I have tried and searched everything but cannot get the solution...Please help

[image]

Comment: Pls, provide the source code in which you set the click listener.

Comment: Hello and Welcome . Please post your code

Comment: Where is your code?